# How do I compare 80 md5sums with each other in bash

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash

I have to compare md5sums of 80 copies of same file with each other and report a failure on a mismatch. How do I do it effectively in bash? I am looking for an elegant algorithm to do it.

Comment: So are all of these files supposed to be identical, and you're trying to find any that aren't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
md5sum FILES > MD5SUMS.md5
cut -c1-32 < MD5SUMS.md5 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

will return something like this:

```
  1 485fd876eef8e941fcd6fc19643e5e59
  1 585fd876eef8e941fcd6fc19643e5e59
  5 385fd876eef8e941fcd6fc19643e5e59
```

Reading: 5 files have the same checksum, two other have "individual" checksums. I assume, that the majority is right, so an additional

```
| tail -1 | cut -c 9-
```

returns the checksum of the last line. Now filter everything else (and put the parts together):

```
md5sum FILES > MD5SUMS.md5
grep -v "$(cut -c1-32 < MD5SUMS.md5 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -c 9-)" MD5SUMS.md5 | cut -c35-
```

This will print the filenames of the non-majority files.

Answer (score 3):

```
md5sum FILES | sed 's/ .*$//' | sort -u
```

If you get more than one line of output, you have a mismatch.

(This doesn't tell you where the mismatch is.)

Putting it together, and replacing the `sed` command with a somewhat less terse `awk` command:

```
count=$(md5sum "$@" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l)
if [ $count -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo "Everything matches"
else
    echo "Nope"
fi
```

Comment: `sed 's/ .*$//'` is less cryptically written `cut -d' ' -f1`, but +1.

Comment: Or even less cryptic: `awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: I was working on a larger solution that would identify the files with a different sum, but it's probably not worth the huge amount of extra work over your one liner.  Besides you can always "md5sum FILES | grep BADSUM" to find the file with the bad sum afterwards

Comment: @dj_segfault: Better yet, save the md5sums to a file so you don't have to recompute them.

Comment: an alternative: `md5sum FILES | sort | uniq -w 32 -u` -- prints out only the lines that occur once.

Comment: @evilotto: Nice, but it misses cases where there are multiple mismatches, for example where 78 of the files are consistent and the other 2 match each other.

Answer (score 1):

The output of:

```
md5sum $files | sort -k 1,2
```

is a list of the checksums in sorted order, with the corresponding file names afterwards.  If you need to eyeball the results, this might be sufficient.  If you need to identify odd-ball results, you have to decide on the presentation.  You say you've got 80 copies of 'the same file'.  Suppose there are actually 10 copies of each of 8 versions of 'the file'.  How are you going to decide which is correct and which is bogus?  What if you have 41 with one hash and 39 with another - are you sure the 39 are wrong and the 41 correct?  Clearly, it is likely that one hash will predominate, but you'll have to worry about those pesky boundary conditions.

You can also do fancier things, such as:

```
md5sum $files | sort -k 1,2 > sorted.md5
sed 's/ .*//' sorted.md5 | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/' > counted.md5
join -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.2 sorted.md5 counted.md5
```

This gives you an output consisting of the MD5 checksum, repetition count, and file name.  The first `sed` script could be replaced by `awk '{print $1}'` if you prefer.  The second would be replaced by `awk '{printf "%s %s\n", $2, $1}'`, which is probably clearer (and *is* shorter).  The reason for that futzing around is to get rid of the leading spaces in the output of `uniq -c` which confuse `join`.

```
md5sum $files | sort -k 1,2 > sorted.md5
awk '{print $1}' sorted.md5 | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%s %s\n", $2, $1}' > counted.md5
join -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.2 sorted.md5 counted.md5
```

I created some files x1.h, x2.h and x3.h by copying dbatools.h, and set `files=$(ls *.h)`.  The output was:

```
0763af91756ef24f3d8f61131eb8f8f2 1 dblbac.h
10215826449a3e0f967a4c436923cffa 1 dbatool.h
37f48869409c2b0554d83bd86034c9bf 4 dbatools.h
37f48869409c2b0554d83bd86034c9bf 4 x1.h
37f48869409c2b0554d83bd86034c9bf 4 x2.h
37f48869409c2b0554d83bd86034c9bf 4 x3.h
5a48695c6b8673373d30f779ccd3a3c2 1 dbxglob.h
7b22f7e2373422864841ae880aad056d 1 dbstringlist.h
a5b8b19715f99c7998c4519cd67f0230 1 dbimglob.h
f9ef785a2340c7903b8e1ae4386df211 1 dbmach11.h
```

This can be further processed as necessary (for example, with `sort -k2,3nr` to get the counts in decreasing order, so the deviant files appear last).  You have the names of the duplicate files grouped together along with a count telling you how many there are each duplication.  What you do next depends on you.

A real production script would use temporary file names instead of hard-coded names, of course, and would clean up after itself.